# CKEditor widget: how do I attach css in onLoad

Tags: javascript, widget, ckeditor

I'm writing a CKEditor widget. As I am trying to make it easily distributable, I want to make my css external. While this syntax works:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('myplugin', {
    requires: 'widget',
    icons: 'myplugin',
    init: function(editor) {
        CKEDITOR.dialog.add('myplugin', this.path + 'dialogs/myplugin.js');
        var self = this;
        editor.on('contentDom', function() {
            editor.document.appendStyleSheet(CKEDITOR.getUrl(self.path + 'css/style.css'));
        });
    }
});
```

I found that CKSource uses `onLoad: function(editor){}` in their `image2` widget to attach css. This looks more canonical than my code. I'm getting `editor = undefined` though. What's the catch?

Update:

I'm using the framed option and I definitely want to stay DRY through `.appendStyleSheet()` to user-facing page as well as to the wysiwyg framed editor. However, I still have problem with init/beforeInit:function(editor), where `editor` does not seem to have `document` property populated at that very moment. When I do `window.ed = editor` though, then I can access the `window.ed.document` in the console once the page is ready. So, is there any kind of deferred promise going on there? Maybe I'm complicating things, but I definitely want to append a distributable stylesheet and remove it easily.

I found this working:

```
    beforeInit: function(
        var ccss = CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss;
        if(typeof ccss == 'string'){
            ccss = [ccss];
        }
        ccss.push('/css/style.css'); // <-- my css installed at website root

        CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = ccss;
        console.log(CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss);
    },
```

While the issue with isolated css stylesheet might sound over-complicated, I want to achieve an easily demoable state without the need to touch existing files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in the [image2 plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/image2/plugin.js#L24) stylesheet is not added to `editor` instance, but using [`CKEDITOR.addCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-addCss):

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'image2', {
    ...
    onLoad: function( editor ) {
        CKEDITOR.addCss( ' ... ' );
    }
} );
```

It is a mistake that the `editor` is specified as an argument - it always will be null.

If you want to add stylesheet manually using [`document.appendStyleSheet`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.document-method-appendStyleSheet), then do it on `init`, or `beforeInit`, not on `onLoad`.

Altough, you should know that `contentDom` will be fired multiple times for one document, e.g. when setting data. So in your case stylesheet would be added many times. Therefore, if you want to add a stylesheet for the framed editor (the one using `iframe`), you can use [`config.contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss), and if you want to add it for inline editor, then you can freely call:

```
CKEDITOR.document.appendStyleSheet( ... );
```

In plugin's `onLoad` (will be called only once). So most likely you'll want to do both things, to handle inline and framed editors.